# computing FID metric using Torchmetric

Tags: image

I have a 2 folders one containing un-preprocessed images from the dataset, and one with the un-preprocessed generated images, I want to calculate the FID between them but I can't figure it out I found this code by torchmetrics :

```
>>> import torch
>>> _ = torch.manual_seed(123)
>>> from torchmetrics.image.fid import FrechetInceptionDistance
>>> fid = FrechetInceptionDistance(feature=64)
>>> # generate two slightly overlapping image intensity distributions
>>> imgs_dist1 = torch.randint(0, 200, (100, 3, 299, 299), dtype=torch.uint8)
>>> imgs_dist2 = torch.randint(100, 255, (100, 3, 299, 299), dtype=torch.uint8)
>>> fid.update(imgs_dist1, real=True)
>>> fid.update(imgs_dist2, real=False)
>>> fid.compute()
tensor(12.7202)
```

and here is my code so far, any ideas ?

```
import torch
import torchmetrics
from torchmetrics.image.fid import _TORCH_FIDELITY_AVAILABLE
from torchmetrics.image.fid import FrechetInceptionDistance
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import os
import pathlib

# Define transforms to resize and normalize images
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((299, 299)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),  # Convert images to PyTorch tensors
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], std=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5])  # Normalize images
])

def load_images_from_folder(folder):
    image_paths = pathlib.Path(folder).glob("*.*")
    images = [transform(Image.open(img_path)) for img_path in image_paths]
    images = torch.stack(images)
    return images

def calculate_fid_for_folders(folder1, folder2):
    # Load images from folders and apply transformations
    real_images = load_images_from_folder(folder1)
    fake_images = load_images_from_folder(folder2)

    # Initialize FID metric
    fid = FrechetInceptionDistance(normalize=True)

    # Update FID metric with real and fake images
    fid.update(real_images, real=True)
    fid.update(fake_images, real=False)

    # Compute FID score
    fid_score = fid.compute()
    print(f"FID: {float(fid.compute())}")

# Example usage:
folder1 = "/content/output_images"
folder2 = "/content/genearated_images"
fid_score = calculate_fid_for_folders(folder1, folder2)
```